# How to get twillio CallStatus in android

Tags: php, android, callback, twilio, twilio-php

I am using app to app calling in android using twilio sdk, but  now i am facing a problem to get call status whether it is answered, no answer, busy,etc etc. i am not able to get call status. If i hangup call from dialer end but it cannnot disconnect from the reciever side.If anyone have idea regarding this please share with me to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you show us your code. Also if you are using Android SDK why did you flagged this question as twilio-php?